# A RenderFlex overflowed by 52 pixels on the bottom

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a problem with Flutter (Dart) RenderFlex overflowed pixels. How to fix the following error?........................
I am getting an warning of **A RenderFlex overflowed by 52 pixels on the bottom.**
Can anyone fix this??

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          child: ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              "\$${catalog.price}".text.bold.xl4.red800.make(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all(MyTheme.darkBluishColor),
                child: "Buy".text.make(),
              ).wh(100, 50)
            ],
          ).p32(),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Hero(
                  tag: Key(catalog.id.toString()),
                  child: Image.network(catalog.image))
              .h32(context),
          Expanded(
            child: VxArc(
              arcType: VxArcType.CONVEY,
              edge: VxEdge.TOP,
              child: Container(
                width: context.screenWidth,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    catalog.name.text.xl4
                        .bold
                        .make(),
                    catalog.desc.text.textStyle(context.captionStyle).xl.make(),
                    " Eos ipsum voluptua eirmod elitr, no dolor dolor amet eirmod dolor labore dolores magna. Amet vero vero vero kasd"
                        .text
                        .textStyle(context.captionStyle)
                        .make()
                        .p16()
                  ],
                ).py64(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you have one Expanded widget in a Column or a Row every child must be wrap with Expanded

Comment: i have tried to wrapp both child container and child column...but the warning is still showing @mariofrancois

Comment: problem Solved..... just need to wrapp the column with SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I used a SingleChildscrollView for the body of the scaffold and it solved the problem for me